# How to use declare custom typedef for QListIterator

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I want to use QListIterator, example shown here:  https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistiterator.html

I have declared a typedef for the list containing QStringList:

```
    typedef QList<QStringList> slstStringList;
```

I want to declare a type that is an iterator for the above, I first tried:

```
    typedef QListIterator<slstStringList> slstIterator;
```

However that didn't work, on looking at the link I posted above I changed it to:

```
    typedef QListIterator<QStringList> slstIterator;
```

The compiler doesn't like this either, I get:

```
    error: no matching function for call to 'QListIterator<QStringList>::QListIterator()'
```

What have I done wrong?

Here is an example of where I have tried to use both:

```
    for( slstIterator it(clsResetCfg::mslstWiFi); it.hasNext(); ) {
        QStringList slstDetails = it.next();
        ...
    }
```

The above works and compiles ok, the error was in a static initialisation of an iterator where I had not specified the static list member, I've changed this now to:

```
    slstStringList clsResetCfg::mslstWiFi;
    slstIterator clsResetCfg::msitWiFi(clsResetCfg::mslstWiFi);
```

Now all is right in the world :)

Comment: It seems you are creating `slstIterator` instance without passing any `QList` object as parameter. QListIterator has only one ctor overload which accepts `QList`.

Comment: @rafix07, the parameter is the typedef "slstStringList"

Comment: Show the code where `slstIterator` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef QListIterator<QStringList> slstIterator;
```

This is correct, but you need to pass a reference to the list itself to the constructor once you instantiate it:

```
slsIterator it{myList};
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, see my edit, this fixed the issue.